# How to find xpath of a element in a web page?

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver

I want to find the xpath of an element from a webpage to automate the UI validation using Selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

For starter, you can right click on any element in the browser window and click on inspect.This should open browser developer tools and the html for the clicked element should be highlighted.Now, right click on the highlighted html and select Copy-> copy XPath.

You should always try to get a xpath which is less likely to change in future to make the tests robust.